# How to add Azure vm from other resource group to the application insight?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-vm

I want to add a Azure vm to the application insights. By default vm's from the same resource group is available under monitor resource group. but didn't found any option to add vm from other RG to the application insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable two or more Azure VMs across a specified subscription or resource group by using PowerShell.

Reference:

[Enable Azure Monitor for VMs using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-enable-at-scale-powershell)